# Why does service injection in app component cause undefined for URL parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, url-parameters

I have a service where I read couple of parameters from the URL. looks good till I try to inject the service in the `constructor` of the `app.component.ts` or I try to call a service method from the `app.component.ts`. Then the url-parameters are undefined.

Any idea what could be the reason for that?

**`my-service.service.ts`**:

```
...
public param1;
constructor(public router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.param1 = 
     this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams['todo'];
    console.log('param1: ' + this.param1); // returns undefined if the service is injected in app.component
}
....
```

**`app.component.ts`**:

```
...
import { MyService } from './service/my-service.service';
....
constructor(private http: HttpClient, public myService: MyService) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What if you try to parse the URL in the `ngOnInit` hook ?

Comment: It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370474/angular-activated-route-paramsmap-empty-depending-on-where-i-specify-the-service

Comment: @trichetriche: `ngOnInit()` in `app.component.ts`? I did give it a try, but din't work. The issue is exactly when I inject the service in the in `app.component.ts` constructor.

Comment: No, in the `ngOninit` of the service.

Comment: @trichetriche: unfortunately it doesn't help... the service doesn't even fire `ngOnInit()`, so therefore I even can't `console.log('param1: ' + this.param1)`. Nothing happens in other words.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't fire ? Maybe that's your issue !

Comment: Here is what I tried in the service: `ngOnInit() {this.param1 = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams['todo']; console.log('param1: ' + this.param1);}`. nothing comes out in chrome console then.

Comment: @Eliseo: Yes, I'am using `canActivte` for some routes which I want to protect. But How can it be related to it?

Comment: Change 'public myService: MyService' to 'private myService: MyService'. Only then Angular directly instantiates it.

Comment: Sorry, I din't read your question :(. I think that you can try to use Location.path https://angular.io/api/common/Location#path , not router)

Comment: @DiabolicWords: no way.. always returns undefined even when using it as `private`

Comment: You say that you get `undefined` when the service is injected in `AppComponent` ... when do you NOT get `undefined`? Are you injecting it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

When we pass some params we always do it this way:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ){ 
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let todo = params['todo'];
      });
  }
```

Maybe you have to move the subscription to ngOnInit() but normally this should work.

Comment: I did give it a try in the service, but unfortunately it didn't help...